# PHP request to Google API for google reviews returns false?

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to get my establishments reviews from Google on my website. I think I figured out how to call the API, because after lots of trying I don't get autentifications errors anymore.
But the return in the dump is just a "false" bool.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong ?

```
<?php

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "00925334976-bgoe7tarvjisj9s6do9lgafmp4se7n99.apps.googleusercontent.com:OCSPX-WTrT5wshXVKInEUgWoab71uiaduY");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

var_dump(CallAPI('GET','https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/00925334976-bgoe7tarvjisj9s6do9lgafmp4se7n99.apps.googleusercontent.com/locations/ChIJq2WiArxx5kcRWeHeXpoao90/reviews&key=OCSPX-WTrT5wshXVKInEUgWoab71uiaduY
'))

?>
```

(I deleted some chars from my API keys here, so to not share them openly here ^^")

Comment: The Google endpoint is `https` so I would suggest using options in your curl config to deal with SSL connections correctly. Download a copy of `cacert.pem` from the web and set the necessary options ( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST & CURLOPT_CAINFO ) - probably a good idea to send some sort of useragent string in the request too?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just me not registering a credit card on the Google API interface, because they charge you for API calls of this nature outside of a certain quota. Which is to remain my best guess because I don't have permission from accountings to register valid payment informations for this, so I can't try, but it's pretty clear in the doc once you found the why of it.

Professor Abronsius comment was also correct, I was missing required options in my request and a valid certificate.